# Progress bar in GWR in R language?

Tags: r, progress-bar, geography, gwr

when i start a gwr process (in various libraries) i have to wait until it is done. But there is no indication (e.g progress bar or % completion indicator) as to where the processing is?

for example I cannot see any progress bar when running the below:

```
cl <- makeCluster(detectCores())
ab_gwr <- gwr(eq1, 
              data = block.data,
              adapt = abw, 
              gweight = gwr.Gauss,
              hatmatrix = T, 
              se.fit = T,
              cl = cl)
stopCluster(cl)
```

is this normal? am I missing something?

Is there a GWR library in `R` language that shows progress bar? or is there any other way to implement it?

(i have used spgwr, GWmodel, and others)